# How to solve MySQL delimiter syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, delimiter

I'm trying to change the MySQL command delimiter so I can create a procedure with multiple commands in it. However, the delimiter command does not seem to be recognised on MySQL 5.1.47. I tested it on MySQL 5.0.91, and it did work there.

```
DELIMITER //;
DELIMITER ;//
```

I'm trying to run this from phpmyadmin, in both situations. Using 5.0.91 instead isn't an option because I need to use events (`CREATE EVENT`).

Error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'DELIMITER //' at line 1

Is there a reason it's not working, or is there an alternative to accomplish the same thing (creating a procedure with multiple queries)?

Comment: I've read that `DELIMITER` isn't really a MySQL command, it's a client command. Does this mean that PHPMyAdmin needs to support it as opposed to MySQL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`DELIMITER` is not a MySQL command. It's a command that your MySQL client needs to support. I was running PHPMyAdmin 2.8.2.4, which didn't support it. When I upgraded to the newest version, which is currently 3.4.9, it worked just fine. Your MySQL version has nothing to do with `DELIMITER` and whether it's supported or not.

Also note that some clients might have a bug with `DELIMITER` being case-sensitive where either only the lowercase `delimiter` or the uppercase `DELIMITER` works.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to delimit the DELIMIT statements

```
DELIMITER //

procedure here etc

DELIMITER ;
```

Exactly as per ["Defining Stored Programs"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html) in the MySQL docs.

And if you can control versions, the latest is 5.5.20. Why not use that?

Edit:

The error message indicates an error in the previous statement... if this can't be seem force it thus

```
; /* <- force previous statement termination */ DELIMITER //

procedure here etc

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I can't control versions, I just happen to have multiple environments running different versions.

Also, the suggestion you posted didn't work. The same error message appears.

Comment: @Patrickdev: the error will be in your previous statement which will be unterminated ...

Comment: I tested this with just this command. There's no previous statement. Besides, if there was a syntax issue, wouldn't it be throwing an error on other versions as well?