# DELIMITER in mysql does not work

Tags: mysql

The below code works correctly when I use command line (mysql.exe) to execute, but incorrect when I use SQL Query in phpmyadmin or using ScriptRunner (Java) to execute.

The error: **Error Syntax execute DELIMITER $$**

How can I solve this problem?

```
-- Procedures
-- 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `upload_photo`(
IN owner_id int, IN photo_name text, IN photo_url text, IN thumbnail text
)
begin
declare inserted_id int unsigned default 0;
INSERT INTO photo(`owner_id`, `photo_name`, `photo_url`, `thumbnail`) VALUES(owner_id, photo_name, photo_url, thumbnail);
 set inserted_id = last_insert_id();
 select * from photo where photo_id = inserted_id;
end$$

-- 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Use a different delimiter, perhaps?

Comment: @MikeW: Thanks for reply. But I got the same error. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017269/mysql-delimiter-syntax-error)

Comment: @Rik. Thanks for supporting. But I don't think this post can solve my problem. If you can. Please help me.

Comment: What version of phpmyadmin are you using? Does it have a delimiter-input-box below the sql-statement?

Comment: Not all versions of phpMyAdmin recognise the delimiter command; instead, one can use the Delimiter input box beneath the SQL input box. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454071/how-do-i-write-an-sp-in-phpmyadmin-mysql/2498437#2498437)

Comment: I'm using Java to execute command (ScriptRunner.Java)

Comment: I don't know ScriptRunner personally but i think it also doesn't know the `DELIMITER` keyword. But can't you set the delimiter with `setDelimiter("$$", true)` before the `Runscript` and leave out the `DELIMITER` keywords?

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin uses mysqli which doesn't support delimiter. See if delimiter is needed at all. I am running a script with multiple rows and my MySQL runs all of them with semicolons as delimiters.

Comment: Just checked. Delimiter is not needed for MySQL. Only needed to pass queries. Mysqli->query only sends one query (you would need mysqli->multi_query). So since you can only pass one query, delimiter is not needed because it will always be one query regardless how many semicolons it will have.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/mybatis/migrations/issues/49#issuecomment-224165340) and it works for me (i'm using ScriptRunner):

just use `-- @DELIMITER $$` instead of `DELIMITER $$`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue where my DELIMITER statement was breaking when run via Flyway despite working when I ran it through my sql client.

The issue was either indentation or hidden special characters because formatting the code in the IDE fixed the issue.