# Mysql trigger delimiter in version 5.5.5

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

I've created a mysql trigger on before insert to behave just like an autoincrement field starting from 1110

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS set_nr_claim_AI;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER set_nr_claim_AI BEFORE INSERT ON users_claim
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     DECLARE max_nr INT;
     SET max_nr = (SELECT MAX(nr_claim) FROM users_claim);
     IF max_nr IS NULL OR max_nr = 0 THEN
        SET NEW.nr_claim = 1100;
     ELSE
        SET NEW.nr_claim = max_nr +1;
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

In mysql version 5.5.5 I have this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

But all works fine in version 5.6 of mysql and I could not find the solution.

I need to resolve also on older version of mysql(my staging environment has 5.5.5)

Comment: did you tried using delimiter //

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam yes, i've tried // and | also as a delimiter. same result.

Comment: try it as delimiter // or leave it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017269/mysql-delimiter-syntax-error

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to resolve the problem. All I needed is to add a new line after DELIMITER ;